# PHP - Commercial round

Tags: php

I want to make commercial round to prices (with PHP)

For example :

15.55 becomes 15.60

15.54 becomes 15.50

147.77 becomes 147.80

==> Always zero in the end.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the precision parameter of php's round function.

```
$result = number_format(round(15.5, 1), 2);
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 2):

You can act in two steps :

- first, use [**`round()`**](https://www.php.net/round) to round your values to one decimal : 15.6
- and, then, use [**`number_format()`**](https://www.php.net/number_format) to display them with two decimals *(and thousand separators, if needed)*

For example, the following portion of code :

```
var_dump( number_format( round(15.55, 1), 2) );
var_dump( number_format( round(15.54, 1), 2) );
var_dump( number_format( round(147.77, 1), 2) );
```

Will give you :

```
string '15.60' (length=5)
string '15.50' (length=5)
string '147.80' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use round() http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php with all 3 parameters

```
round($number, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

the zero can be added via number_format()

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = sprintf('%.2F', round($val, 1));
```

[`sprintf()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) does the same as [`number_format()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$rounded = ceil($number * 10) / 10;
```