# Commercial round with comma and point

Tags: php, rounding

I have used this code :

```
$result = number_format(round(15.5, 1), 2);
```

Written in my old post : 
[PHP - Commercial round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499638/php-commercial-round)

I have now problems with the values like : 1,597.30

I get the price as 1.00

How can I do to get the make the round and get the good price format with the prices that have number with thousands.

Comment: `1,597.30` is a string not a number in PHP should be `1597.30`

Comment: If you have the user entering the number, you will have to parse it first to get a real number, not a string. After this you can round and format it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never store a formatted number.

Always store it in its **original format:** `1597.30` This is the only format that works for calculations and formatting.

Use `number_format()` only for outputting the number.

Comment: +1 and the temporary solution is `$number=str_replace(',','',$number)`

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this issue using the following code:

```
$price       = '1,597.30';
$new_price   = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $price));
$result      = number_format(round($new_price, 1), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma and all other formating (except the dot) from your numbers, otherwise comma will be used as decimal separator.